# Want to calculate number of login members in System using Spring SessionAttribute?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working with spring.

Whenever a user Logs In I do the following

```
model.addAttribute("user",user);
```

where model is object of

```
ModelMap model;
```

and adding user in session as

```
@SessionAttribute({"user"});
```

Now I want to calculate how many members are logged In ?
Is that possible in this continues way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach wouldn't work (at least with a lot of extra code), because you are dealing with session objects, which are not normally accessible outside their respective session.

You would have to have an external tracking object to keep track of session authentications 
and sessions destroyed.  You can see and example [here](http://www.codercorp.com/blog/spring/security-spring/tracking-logged-in-users-using-spring-security-httpsessionlistener-in-java-web-application.html).